# How did the Faroese heat their houses?

Tags: everyday-life

As Faroe Islands' *["low temper­atures during the growing season, stormy winter weather, and variable winter temperatures are unfavourable for tree growth"](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4899-1600-6_31)*, there are hardly any trees on Faroe Islands. What have the Faroese used as fuel to warm and light their houses with?

I am asking about period before the Faroese started importing fuel from other places.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They used local [peat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peat)

> In the past driftwood was avidly collected and used for building and furniture rather than burned; heat was provided by peat cut from ground outside the settlement and dried through the summer in peat drying huts that are dotted around the landscape.
>
> <sup>[Visiting the Faroe Islands](http://www.walkingworld.com/Articles/General-info/Going-abroad/Visiting-the-Faroe-Islands.aspx)</sup>

Also

> A couple of generations ago the faroese were still living in their turf-roofed, peat-fired, tarred wooden houses and were wearing their national costume as they had done for centuries.
>
> <sup>[North Atlantic Maritime Cultures: Anthropological Essays on Changing Adaptations](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0ZnGi8b_cgcC&pg=PA63&lpg=PA63&dq=faroes+peat+heating&source=bl&ots=qv7GxUJDB7&sig=VyVdCczEOB0KyQ6KtyUfyM4N138&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq3bGNuazUAhUMJsAKHXoIAVsQ6AEIVjAI#v=onepage&q=faroes%20peat%20heating&f=false)</sup>